# Tool to detect whether I have not received a regular e-mail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I receive an e-mail from our hosted backup provider whenever a backup job has run.
I don't really care about those e-mails unless the backups are unsuccessful, or if I don't get the e-mails (meaning that the jobs have been delayed by some error).

Using e-mail rules, I can easily move the "job success" e-mails and mark them as read, so I don't get them in my inbox.

But is there a way or a tool that can help me to detect whether I haven't received an e-mail from a specific sender for e.g. 24 hours?

E-mail client is Outlook connected to an Exchange server.

Comment: Are the subjects of the emails static and different from one another?

Comment: The subjects are not completely static. They all start with either
"Backup Report [Successful]" or "Backup Report [Failure]" 
followed by the backup job name.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2007/2010/2013 you can create a search folder for that purpose. Create custom search folder and specify sender and received time as a criteria. After that in this folder's properties set **Show total number of items** option.

That's all. Now if you don't see any number next to the folder name, you haven't received the required e-mail.

Comment: That is a good suggestion to tell me if I have received any mails, and I will use it unless I come up with something better.

I would like to have something more automated than me remembering to check the message count of the search folder. For example a tool that will do the check for me, and then e-mailing me if no messages have been received.